# Python - Print output instead of formula

Tags: python, formula, calculation

I'm new with Python and got no experience with any programming languages so far. I have to complete an exercise but I can't get the desired output.

I need to give x a value of 0, 1 and -1.
And y should have the expected outcome of -1.0, 3.0 and -9.0

I created the following code:

```
x = 1
x = float(x)

var="y"
y=input("(3x**3)-(2x**2)+(3x)-1")

print("y =", y)
```

But the print output keeps showing the actual formula and doesn't display the actual (expected) outcome value. Is there anyone that could quickly explain what I'm missing here?

Comment: What is the purpose of the line var="y" ? Also, is it the print statement that you want to change? Or the console output from the "input" statement? (Please post what output you are getting exactly, and what exactly you expect/want)

Comment: What's the relation between the y and the x, do you calculate the y using the x? 
or do you just want to  output 0,1, -1 for the x and  -1.0,3.0,-9.0 for the y?

Comment: You get the formula printed out because `input("(3x**3)-(2x**2)+(3x)-1")` prints what you passed into the console and reads from the stdin. Try inputting something when the formula shows up, it should then print `y = ` and exactly what you typed in.

Comment: Isn't the line `y= (3*x**3)-(2*x**2)+(3*x)-1` a solution ? Typing the formula as a string seems highly non-natural to me.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, there are few problems with the code.
3x,2x Should be 3*x , 2*x

> And then try running the code without the quotes which would not treat
>   it as a string.

Comment: Good point, I had missed the missing `*`. Maybe you should publish the corrected code, it might help Niels93

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple math formula like this :

```
x = [0, 1, -1]

for i in x:
    print float(((3*i)**3)-((2*i)**2)+(3*i)-1)
```

I don't know if it fits your question as it's quite unclear but it returns the values for the formula `3x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 1` evaluted in `0`, `1` and `-1`.

Best

Answer (score 1):

This solution is almost certainly unnecessary for the particular issue being faced by OP, but I include it because it provides a general solution to the problem of printing "value of a string" and not "the literal string" which could be useful. Format strings.

```
x = input("Please enter a x value")
x = float(x)
print(f"y = {(3x**3)-(2x**2)+(3x)-1}")
```

Placing an "f" in front of a string means that anything between "{}" in the string will be evaluated, and the result cast to a string, and printed in that position. It's great.

Answer (score -1):

You declared 2 variables. The first one being var, that has value 'y', and then you declared var y, that asks for input, when you actually enter something it will print it.
It should've been done like this:

```
x = 1
x = float(x)

input = input('Enter a value here: ')
y = ((3*x)**3)-((2*x)**2)+(3*x)-1

print("y =", y)
```

**EDIT:**
I didn't know what do you need the input for, so I just left it there.